# Architecture Verification: Consuming Web Services with .NET MAUI

Tags: architecture, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have designed an architecture for my .NET MAUI application that involves consuming web services. I would like to ensure that I am following best practices and making the most efficient use of the framework. Here are the key components of my architecture:

The backend generates WSDL files that describe the available web services.
I am using dotnet svcutil to generate service classes based on the WSDL files.
The generated service classes are stored in the "Connected Services Folder".
In addition, I have created custom service classes in the "Service Folder" that utilize the generated service classes for interacting with the web services.
The ViewModel classes in the "ViewModel Folder" make use of the service classes to access data and perform business logic.
The View classes in the "View Folder" bind to the ViewModel classes for displaying data to the user.
[image]

I would like to get insights and recommendations on this architecture. Are there any potential issues or improvements that I should consider? Are there any best practices for consuming web services in a .NET MAUI architecture that I might be missing?

Thank you for your guidance and suggestions!

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Asking for critique and feedback is not on topic for SO.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I apologize if my question wasn't clear. What I meant to ask is where I can post this type of question. Would GitHub be a better place?

Comment: I guess open a new discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions